# `SpatialGraphDistribution` with `DirectedEdges` doesn't work

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I want to create a random graph with `SpatialDegreeDistribution` and want the edges to be directed.

```
T = SpatialGraphDistribution[10, 0.3, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance]
g = RandomGraph[T, VertexLabels -> Automatic, DirectedEdges -> True]
DirectedGraphQ[g]
```

The visual graph generated here is without any directed edges and it is confirmed to be undirected by the output of `DirectedGraphQ[g]` being `False`. However, if I use `DegreeGraphDistribution` then there is no issue generating directed random graphs.

What am I missing here? Why doesn't the directive `DirectedEdges` work?

Edit :

Implementing `DirectedGraph[g]` solves the issue by generating directed edges but still doesn't explain why `DirectedEdges` fails to work at the initial construction.